# Solve the PDE $u_{xx}+u=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Solve the PDE $u_{xx}+u=0$. The answer is $u(x,y)=f(y)cos(x)+g(y)sin(x)$ but I don't understand where the cos and sin terms come from. I know that the solution to $u_{xx}=o$ is $u(x,y)=f(y)x+g(y)$.

Comment: solve the ordinary DE $u''+u=0$. Observe that you need to write $f(y)$ for the constant term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$u_{xx}+u=0$$
Since you differentiate wrt x twice, consider the ode 
$$\frac   {d^2u}{dx^2}+u=0$$
$$r^2+1=0 \implies r=\pm i$$
$$u(x,y)=K_1(y)\cos(x)+K_2(y)\sin(x)$$